# Scrolling effect - fixed, 'blocked' container changes when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fixed

I'd like to achieve effect of the fixed container that changes in the last phase of scrolling. I'm not sure how to call it professionally, so sorry for lack of appropriate words. 
Actually, how it should be called? :)

I mean sth like that: https://media.giphy.com/media/26gsscmNiRJW039XG/source.gif
The effect can be seen live on the UX London page http://2016.uxlondon.com/

I'm not superexperienced with JS, but if you could share any tutorials or examples with similar effects it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might use this example for that purpose:

https://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/yLfAG

js: $( window ).ready(function() {

```
var wHeight = $(window).height();

$('.slide')
  .height(wHeight)
  .scrollie({
    scrollOffset : -50,
    scrollingInView : function(elem) {

      var bgColor = elem.data('background');

      $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);

    }
  });
```

});

Comment: Thanks a lot! it partly fulfill my goal. However in the example https://media.giphy.com/media/26gsscmNiRJW039XG/source.gif the right container is 'fixed' and changes in the very last moment. I've no idea how to do this.